# Is it a good idea to use a trigger to record a time a row is updated?

Tags: sql

I hate triggers. I've been tripped up by them way too many times. But I'd like to know if it's a better to specify the time every time a row is updated or let a trigger take care of it to keep code to a minimum?

Just to clarify, the table the trigger would be on would have a column called something like `LastModified`

The particular scenario I'm dealing with is I am one of the developers who uses a database with about 400 stored procedures. There are about 20 tables that would have this `LastModified` column. These tables would be updated by about 10 different stored procedures each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers can definitely be a huge problem, especially if there are multiple layers of them.  It makes debugging, performance tuning, and understanding the data logic almost impossible.

But if you keep your design to a single layer (a trigger for the table), and it is used soley for auditing (i.e. putting the updated time), I don't think that'll be a big problem at all.

Equally, if you are using a stored procedure to be the actor to your tables and views, I think it would make just as much sense (and be a lot easier to remember and look back on) to have your stored procedure put in the current datetime stamp.  I think that's a great design.

But if you're using ad hoc queries, and you have a `datetime` field as `not null`, it will be a hindrance to remember to call the current datetime.  Obviously this won't be a problem with the aforementioned two ideas with the stored procedure or the trigger.

So I think in this situation, is should be personal preference (as long as you don't make a *string* of triggers that become spaghetti).

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a TimeStamp column (in MySql). If it's MSSQL, just note that the timestamp column is a serial number, not a DateTime data type.

Generally, I avoid triggers like the plague (close to on par with cursors) and so always just update the column manually.  To me, it helps reinforce the business logic.  But in truth, "better" is a a personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, triggers are most useful as a bottleneck if you have a table that needs certain business logic applied for every update, and you have updates coming from different sources.

For example suppose you have php and python apps that both use the database. You could try and remember to update the python code every time you update the php, and vice versa, and hope that they both work the same. Or you could use a trigger, so that no matter what client connects, the same thing will happen to the table.

In most other cases triggers are a bad idea and will cause more pain than they are worth.

Answer (score 1):

Its true that some triggers can often be a source of confusion and frustration when debugging, especially when there are cascading foreign key updates.

But they do have their use. 
In this case, you have a choice of updating 400 stored procedures, and updating the date manually. If you miss one of those stored procs, then the field is as good as useless. 
Also while triggers 'hide' functionality, the same can be said of explicitly updating it in a stored procedure. What happens when someone writes a new stored procedure, you need to document that the field should be updated.

Personally if its critical the field is up to date, I would use a trigger. Use an INSTEAD OF trigger, so that instead of doing an update and that triggering the trigger, you are simply overriding the insert statement.